# Reduce TLS record size in Netty?

Tags: netty, tls1.2

I'm currently using Netty 4.1.24 for a Server communicating via a Socket Connection over TLS 1.2 with the Client.

Currently the TLS Record Size ("wrap") is 16 Kb as defined in the specification (see implementation in [SslHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/netty-4.1.24.Final/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.java); the relevant variables are `MAX_PLAINTEXT_LENGTH` and `wrapDataSize`)

Due to memory constraints on the client, I do have to reduce the TLS record size generated by the Server. I'm using `setWrapDataSize` to limit the size, but Netty does not use it (it still creates 16 Kb Records).

I'm using the following Snippet in the `ChannelInitializer` to create the `SSLEngine`/`SslHandler`

```
final SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(keyManagerFactory)
    .trustManager(trustManagerFactory)
    .clientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRE)
    .build();

LOGGER.info("Default SSL Provider: {}", SslContext.defaultServerProvider());

final SslHandler sslHandler = sslCtx.newHandler(channel.alloc());
// Currently not working
sslHandler.setWrapDataSize(1024);
```

In order to check the size of the records, I use WireShark and I still see a record sitze of 16388 Bytes.

My Default SslContext Provider is JDK.

Question is: how do I enforce Netty to create smaller records?

Note: I also reduced the size of the Send-Buffer in the `SocketChannelConfig`, which also had no effect. (cause its a TLS related thing).

Comment: Are you using the Jdk or OpenSsl provider ?

Comment: My default Provider is JDK (Question updated)

Comment: In the mean time I tried both Provides (JDK and OpenSsl with netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.8). It seems that both implemented ignore the ```setWrapdataSize()```

Comment: @NormanMaurer I just wanted to see, if you have any idea/hint.